# Insert Currency into Access Database C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to insert currency in access data I am using datatype currency with general number format here is my c# code

```
 decimal price = decimal.Parse(vCCY_Rate.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);

  SCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCY_Rate", price);  
 nReturnValue = (int)SCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

where **vCCY_Rate** is double but this always store 1 in database and some time 0 
can you tell me how to store currency in database access using c#. I have data of precion 6 that is also mentioned in currency datatype with general format and presicion

**SQL Command**

```
     OleDbConnection SConnection = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbCommand SCmd = new OleDbCommand();

    Save_Main("INSERT into tblOprCurrency_Rate ([CCY_ID_From],  [CCY_ID_To] , [CCY_Active] , [CCY_Rate] ,[CCY_Chr]) VALUES (? , ? , ? ,? ,? )", cmbCurrency_From.SelectedItem.Value, cmbCurrency_To.SelectedItem.Value, Convert.ToDouble(txtCCY_Rate.Text), chkCCY_Active.Checked, 0, hdfSr_ID.Value);




      public int Save_Main(string vQuery, string vCCY_ID_From, string vCCY_ID_To, double vCCY_Rate, bool bCCY_Active, int vIsUpdate, string vCCY_SrNo)
    {



        sErrorCode = "";
        int nReturnValue = -1;
        try
        {
            decimal price = (decimal)vCCY_Rate;
           // decimal price = decimal.Parse(vCCY_Rate.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
            SCmd.CommandText = vQuery;
            SCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCY_ID_From", vCCY_ID_From);
            SCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCY_ID_To", vCCY_ID_To);

            SCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCY_Rate", price);  
            SCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCY_Active", bCCY_Active);
            SCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCY_Chr", Convert.ToDouble(0));
            SCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCY_SrNo", vCCY_SrNo);

            SCmd.Connection = SConnection;
            SCmd.CommandTimeout = pSQL_CommandTimeOut;
            SDataAdapter.SelectCommand = SCmd;
            SConnection.Open();
            nReturnValue = (int)SCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

CCY_Rate is currency datatype and generat format with 6 decimal places in ACCESS

Comment: 1 or 0..? what is the input lets start with that. We can't help you like this

Comment: What's the value of `vCCYRate`? And what is the value of `price` after the `decimal.Parse`?

Comment: Is there an issue with the code you posted?

Comment: any double value like 120.00 etc

Comment: just I want to insert currency in access db with precision 6

Comment: (it will probably not solve this problem, but) Please use `decimal price = (decimal)vCCY_Rate;` instead of the detour through string.

Comment: You don't need to convert to string to store as currency. In database it is finally a number. So you need to convert send numeric value to database instead of string.

Comment: numeric value how its is decimal like 120.10

Comment: @HansKesting not works it store -1

Comment: @RenéVogt the issue is selection of proper datatype to store decimal value like 21.12 and 212.005 in database of access with c# ,So which datatype in access and c# will be used to save data

Comment: What is your sql command? Please add that to your question.

Comment: What is the current datatype in the database?

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to use decimal for all currency related values in the first place, rather than convert double.

Comment: Now see i have added code and db info

Comment: You are using named parameters in your code & positional parameters in your query - Rate & Active are in the wrong order. Also you have added 6 parameters, but only 5 question mark parameters.

Comment: solves thanks the parameter were in wrong order

Comment: I should have added that as answer rather than a comment - so you can let other readers know it is solved. I have now done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using named parameters in your code & positional parameters in your query - Rate & Active are in the wrong order.

Also you have added 6 parameters, but only 5 positional (question mark) parameters.